# Objective C code works on iPad but not on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

So Ive got the following lines of code in Objective C:

```
NSLog(@"begin");
[channel loadChannel:@"c12"];
NSLog(@"end");
```

and in the `loadChannel:` method of the `channel` object I have this code:

```
- (void) loadChannel: (NSString*) channelId {
    NSLog(@"loadChannel");
    NSLog(@"channelId: %@",channelId);
    /* more code */
}
```

On the iPad simulator everything works fine, exactly as expected. My log output shows:

```
begin
loadChannel
channelId: c12
end
```

However on the iPhone simulator its a different story. It is as if its skipping over the `loadChannel:` method. My log output shows:

```
begin
end
```

Other than this there are no errors kicked out by Xcode.

Is there any reason that anybody is aware of why the iPhone would just ignore certain methods when the iPad wont?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Set a breakpoint on `[channel loadChannel:@"c12"];` and make sure `channel` is not nil.

Comment: Also delete your project on your simulator and then run it :)

Comment: do you have different targets for the iPhone and iPad version? If so, you might have different class files linked to each target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `channel` object is `nil`. Check how you are creating this object.
And also check iOS version of your ipad and iphone.